# How many concurrent sessions in IBM DB2 9.7 are normal?

Tags: db2, monitor

I am using the db2top command to profile my DB2 9.7 database. It shows around 1000 sessions, but I can't get any sense on about what those sessions are. We have a few concurrent testers testing the application. Does the 1000 sessions sound reasonable? We have some problems with DB connections unexpectedly dropping...

Comment: What is the "Application Name" for these connections?  Are you using the Database Partitioning Feature, and if so, how many database partitions do you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few concurrent testers than 1000 sessions is not reasonable. There is no reason why each user should have more than 1 connection.

You should verify if connections are closed properly after usage, even if there has been some error in SQL execution.

You did not tell anything about the type of system you are developing, but in general, if it is a client-server system, each client should use a maxmimum of 1 connection and release it when the client program is closed. On a server application you should use a connection pool and the maximum number of connections in use should be equal to the maximum number of concurrent users you have.